# How to specify condition in Count()?

Tags: php, mysql, count

I only want to count the row that have `status=0`
example `a_no` column has `status=0` and its count as one

this is my query

```
select date, count(DISTINCT no_a) as Transaction, 
     CASE when status=0 then count(distinct no_a) end as Success
     from transfer_tx_201503
```

Comment: why didnt you use simple where clause??

Comment: if i use where its also filter the transaction which is i want to show all the number even if the status!=0

Comment: so you want to count both the rows which have status =0 and as transaction

Comment: no, i want to count number of row that only have status=0 and count as Success

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the condition outside of count:

```
select 
    count(distinct no_a) as Transaction,
    count(distinct case status when 0 then no_a else -1 end case) - 1 as Success
from your_table
```

This should work, assuming no_a is integer and the value -1 is not a valid value.
You simply put all rows with non-zero status in one bucket and then subtract one from the count.

Comment: thank you for your answer but its not what im looking for. I want count status=0 only in Success column. If i use where the transaction will also follow the condition

Comment: Is that what you want (see updated) - count the rows that have status = 0 ?